# OLEDB Access Query not finding data with DateTime Criteria

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

So, I have came across something really strange, I'm querying an Access DB from a C# application. With a simple query as follows -

```
    OleDbDataReader externalAccessReader = null;
    OleDbCommand externalAccessCommand = accessDBFunctions.ExternalAccessCommand(LivedataExternalAccessConnection);

    externalAccessCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from MinuteDataWhole where CurrentDateTime > #12/10/2016 08:43:53# order by CurrentDateTime";
```

When I execute, it returns zero rows -

[image]

So i went directly to the Access db table..

[image]

Ran this query and sure enough, data was returned.

[image]

I can't see anything different that I am doing, the query is exactly the same.

Can anyone see anything obvious?

Comment: Invert the month with the day. In other word. #10/12/2016.....#

Comment: Hmm, this has worked in the C# application, but when I run it in the access DB, it doesnt. Why does it work in C#? still don't understand

Comment: It is the formatting required by the generic nature of OleDb provider for MS-Access. It uses the Invariant Culture. Of course your local MS-Access UI knows it better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is caused by the generic nature of OleDb provider for MS-Access. It uses the Invariant Culture and requires the DateTime constants to be in that format. Of course your local MS-Access UI knows it better and converts your inputs (basically strings) to the correct underlying format required by Access (whatever it is)

However, if you pass a DateTime variable as a parameter of type DateTime this problem should go away

```
OleDbDataReader externalAccessReader = null;
OleDbCommand externalAccessCommand = accessDBFunctions.ExternalAccessCommand(LivedataExternalAccessConnection);

externalAccessCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT * from MinuteDataWhole 
    where CurrentDateTime > @currentDate 
    order by CurrentDateTime";
externalAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("@currentDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Now there is no formatting involved, a DateTime variable is passed and used, *as is* without any kind of intervention from the downlevel layers of OleDb to convert a string in a DateTime.